# "cmd.exe /k pushd %L" doesn't run anymore

Tags: windows-7, dos, explorer

I have since years the following registry key, so I can open a DOS-Box by right-click on a directory of the explorer.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\DOS-Prompt]
"command"="cmd.exe /k pushd %L"
```

It did run until last week. Now, I become the following message and can't find the reason.

```
This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action.
```

or in German

```
Der Datei ist kein Programm zum Ausführen dieser Aktion zugeordnet.
```

The program cmd.exe is in my C:\windows\system32. I have a Windows 7, so the same action is possible with SHIFT+right-click. But my direct link did run... Why not anymore?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry setting is incorrect. It should be like below.

```
[HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\DOS-Prompt\command]
@="cmd.exe /k pushd %L"
```

Answer (score 0):

use `/s` if folder name contains spaces.

```
 [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Folder\shell\DOS-Prompt\command]
 @="cmd.exe /s /k pushd %L"
```